# Getting instance of certain type in Ninject

Tags: c#, binding, inversion-of-control, ninject

I'm binding my instances of classes that inherit from the same interface in Ninject:

```
IOC.Kernel.Bind<IService>.ToConstant(new ServiceA());
IOC.Kernel.Bind<IService>.ToConstant(new ServiceB());
IOC.Kernel.Bind<IService>.ToConstant(new ServiceC());

public interface IService
{
    [...]
}

public class ServiceA : IService { [..] }
public class ServiceB : IService { [..] }
public class ServiceC : IService { [..] }
```

The generic way of retrieving a instance would be `IOC.Get<IService>();` but since I bind three different classes, it wont work.

I want to get a valid instance type based on a enum in my application:

```
public IService GetCurrent()
{
    switch (CurrentServiceEnum)
    {
        case ServiceType.ServiceA:
            return IOC.Get<IService>()// ?? Get type ServiceA
        case ServiceType.ServiceB:
            return IOC.Get<IService>()// ?? Get type ServiceB
        case ServiceType.ServiceC:
            return IOC.Get<IService>()// ?? Get type ServiceC
    }

    return null;
}
```

My problem is that I can't figure out how to get a instance of `IService` of specified type, eg. `ServiceB`.

Ninject docs say that I can actually name each binding and retrieve a valid type like so: `IOC.Get<IService>("ServiceB")` however I don't like the idea of naming by string in this particular case and would rather choose to use generic type (just an example): `IOC.Get<IService>.OfType<ServiceB>()`.

Would Ninject allow me to do that using some method?
Which method should I use to achieve that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Like Ninject says, naming is the right way to go. To avoid using a `string` for the name, you can use the `nameof()` operator, something  like this:

```
IOC.Get<IService>(nameof(ServiceA));
IOC.Get<IService>(nameof(ServiceB));
IOC.Get<IService>(nameof(ServiceC));
```

This will allow you to use a strongly typed name, which in your case happens to be the service `class` itself

Comment: Thanks, this is still better than string since refactoring would include that too. Which is what I wanted.

Answer (score 1):

If you already know the type you want to inject, you could just as well do:

```
Bind<IService, ServiceA>().ToConstant(new ServiceA());
Bind<IService, ServiceB>().ToConstant(new ServiceB());
```

And retrieve it by

```
IResolutionRoot.Get<ServiceB>();
```